# Using element instead of attribute in XSD/XML key/keyref definition

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xsd, xsd-validation

I got some problem with setting up a key/keyref constraint in my XSD/XML file. Here's the example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="PriorityDefinitionFileSchema"
    targetNamespace="myNamespace"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="myNamespace"
    xmlns:this="myNamespace"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
  <xs:element name="PriorityDefinitionFile" type="this:PriorityDefinitionFile">
    <xs:key name="PriorityDefinition_PK">
      <xs:selector xpath="this:AvailablePriorities/this:PriorityDefinition"/>
      <xs:field xpath="Value"/>
    </xs:key>
    <xs:keyref name="PriorityDefinition_FK" refer="this:PriorityDefinition_PK">
      <xs:selector xpath="this:EventPriorityMappings/EventPriorityMapping"/>
      <xs:field xpath="PriorityValue"/>
    </xs:keyref>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="PriorityDefinitionFile">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="AvailablePriorities" type="this:AvailablePriorities"/>
      <xs:element name="EventPriorityMappings" type="this:EventPriorityMappings"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="AvailablePriorities">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="PriorityDefinition" type="this:PriorityDefinition" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="PriorityDefinition">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Value" type="xs:unsignedByte"/>
      <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="Id" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="EventPriorityMappings">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="EventPriorityMapping" type="this:EventPriorityMapping" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="EventPriorityMapping">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="EventNr" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:element name="EventHash" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="PriorityValue" type="xs:unsignedByte"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="Id" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

I'm getting error in Visual Studio saying that my "PriorityDefinition_PK" can not be validated. Key is missing, or key contains empty values.

I added some attributes for testing, cause most examples use attributes. And surprise, if I'm using the "Id" attributes in my field definitions like: `<xs:field xpath:"@Id">` everythink works fine. Because I'm using the XML with DataContractSerializer, I can't use attributes at all.

XSD documentation on http://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_key.asp clearly says that elements and attributes can be used.

So, where is the problem here? I tried various xpaths like ./Value, .//Value etc. but won't accept it.

I'm using this example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PriorityDefinitionFile xmlns="myNamespace">
  <AvailablePriorities>
    <PriorityDefinition Id="0">
      <Value>0</Value>
      <Name>Subsequent Event</Name>
    </PriorityDefinition>
    <PriorityDefinition Id="1">
      <Value>1</Value>
      <Name>Normal Event</Name>
    </PriorityDefinition>
    <PriorityDefinition Id="2">
      <Value>2</Value>
      <Name>RootCause Event</Name>
    </PriorityDefinition>
  </AvailablePriorities>
  <EventPriorityMappings>
    <EventPriorityMapping Id="0">
      <EventNr>31000</EventNr>
      <EventHash>sdosdsadp</EventHash>
      <PriorityValue>2</PriorityValue>
    </EventPriorityMapping>
    <EventPriorityMapping Id="9">
      <EventNr>432432</EventNr>
      <EventHash>sdfdsfd</EventHash>
      <PriorityValue>9</PriorityValue>     <-- Should error here
    </EventPriorityMapping>
  </EventPriorityMappings>
</PriorityDefinitionFile>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've not used the namespace alias 'this' consistently

[image: Diagram from Liquid XML]

```
<xs:element name="PriorityDefinitionFile"
            type="this:PriorityDefinitionFile">
    <xs:key name="PriorityDefinition_PK">
        <xs:selector xpath="this:AvailablePriorities/this:PriorityDefinition"/>
        <xs:field xpath="this:Value"/>
    </xs:key>
    <xs:keyref name="PriorityDefinition_FK"
               refer="this:PriorityDefinition_PK">
        <xs:selector xpath="this:EventPriorityMappings/this:EventPriorityMapping"/>
        <xs:field xpath="this:PriorityValue"/>
    </xs:keyref>
</xs:element>
```

Also your sample data does not have the correct FK's (I've markered up the PK/FK with ** and ##).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Created with Liquid XML 2017 Developer Bundle Edition 15.0.0.0 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<PriorityDefinitionFile xmlns="myNamespace"
                        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                        xsi:schemaLocation="myNamespace file:///D:/Development2017/Liquid/Applications/XmlStudio/Tests/UserSamples/40743074_using-element-instead-of-attribute-in-xsd-xml-key-keyref-definition/MySchema.xsd">
    <AvailablePriorities>
        <PriorityDefinition Id="0">
            ##<Value>0</Value>##
            <Name>Subsequent Event</Name>
        </PriorityDefinition>
        <PriorityDefinition Id="1">
            ##<Value>1</Value>##
            <Name>Normal Event</Name>
        </PriorityDefinition>
        <PriorityDefinition Id="2">
            ##<Value>2</Value>##
            <Name>RootCause Event</Name>
        </PriorityDefinition>
    </AvailablePriorities>
    <EventPriorityMappings>
        <EventPriorityMapping Id="0">
            <EventNr>31000</EventNr>
            <EventHash>sdosdsadp</EventHash>
            **<PriorityValue>2</PriorityValue>**
        </EventPriorityMapping>
        <EventPriorityMapping Id="9">
            <EventNr>432432</EventNr>
            <EventHash>sdfdsfd</EventHash>
            **<PriorityValue>1</PriorityValue>**
        </EventPriorityMapping>
        <EventPriorityMapping Id="10">
            <EventNr>432432</EventNr>
            <EventHash>sdfdsfd</EventHash>
            **<PriorityValue>0</PriorityValue>**
        </EventPriorityMapping>
    </EventPriorityMappings>
</PriorityDefinitionFile>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
I see, I forgot the this-identifier at .../this:EventPriorityMapping...
I'm quite sure that I tried that before...

The problem seems to be the missing identifiers at Value and PriorityValue, but why is that? I thought of this identifier as some "Type-Identifier", but Value and PriorityValue are elements inside a complexType. Little bit confusing...